# Tunning DIH Apache Solr

Tags: solr

can we increase the Apache solr performance for importing data from mysql with dataimport ?
currently i am using :

1. 4 core processor
2. RAM 16 GB
3. HDD 50 GB
4. mysql record 1,2 Millions

for now i get 20 minutes for full import the datas.

Comment: Usually the best thing is to drop DIH and write a small, custom indexer. That way you can more easily spread the load across threads and fetch multiple result sets in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the best way is to drop using DIH (which is single threaded and runs on a single node - so it won't be easily scalable).

By writing a small, custom indexer in a suitable language (or even by using the bundled `post` tool), you can run multiple instances of your indexer, index to different nodes (allowing your content to be processed in parallel) and keep multiple threads open to both your backend database and to Solr.

It's important that you don't use explicit commits when indexing from multiple processes or threads - since that'll kill performance when committing often. Use `commitWithin` instead, telling Solr to automagically issue a commit after x seconds has passed. If you have full control over when all processes / threads have finished, you can issue the commit yourself - i.e. at the end of the indexing process (unless you want documents to become visible while indexing, in that case use `commitWithin`).